# how do I share a dbface application on social media like highcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, highcharts

am building an application that users might need to share on social media, email, export purposes and so on.

the data is loaded via an iframe link, then the chart is loaded by an iframe ad dbface renders it.

how do I share this on social media and also have other export functions like the ones available for highcharts?

please help.

```
    function myFunction(ids='') {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
            var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
                frames[i].style.height = frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px'; 
            }
     }, 3000);
}
<iframe src="http://gbc.me.ke/cra/misreporting/?module=Embed&OBJID=B72B08B94FA70E35D7113352E0C62BD5" name="setdata" id="setdata" onload="myFunction('setdata');">
```

Comment: The questions is too broad - try splitting it into few more precise questions with attached code needed to understand the problem. If this is "like Highcharts", then it's not a Highcharts issue and the `highcharts` tag is misleading.

Comment: ok thanks. Got assistance from their forum.

Comment: If you have the answer for the question you could add it here to close the question.